# QAudioRecorder stop crash application

Tags: qt, audio-recording

I have an application recording micro. When I press a button, recording start or stop (depending state). The first time I execute start/stop but after a certain time, the application crash on stop function. I seems randomly.

#### `//myapp.h`

```
class MyApp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyApp(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyApp();
    void createAudioRecorder();
signals:
    void recordingChanged ( );

public slots:
    void toogleRecord( );
private:
    QAudioRecorder *myAudioRecorder;
    QString pathAudioFile;
};
```

#### `//myapp.cpp`

```
MyApp::MyApp(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    createAudioRecorder();
}

MyApp::~MyApp()
{

}


void MyApp::createAudioRecorder()
{
    myAudioRecorder= new QAudioRecorder(this);
    pathAudioFile = QDir::currentPath();
    pathAudioFile+="/audio.flac";
    myAudioRecorder -> setOutputLocation ( QUrl(pathAudioFile));
    QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
    audioSettings.setCodec("audio/FLAC");
    myAudioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);
}

void MyApp::toogleRecord(){

    qDebug()<<"before,  state myAudioRecorder"<<myAudioRecorder<<myAudioRecorder->state();

    switch (myAudioRecorder->state()) {
    case QMediaRecorder::StoppedState:
        myAudioRecorder->record();
        break;
    case QMediaRecorder::RecordingState :
        myAudioRecorder->stop(); //<------------crash here
        break;
    case QMediaRecorder::PausedState:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
        qDebug()<<"after,  state myAudioRecorder"<<myAudioRecorder<<myAudioRecorder->state()<<"\n";
}
```

I don't understand where that comes from.

---

Edit :
Debug can't help me to find an answer.

I have also display changing state and changing status. It's seems that problem is on starting recording and not on the stopping (before crash audio recorder status isn't "Recording"

Good record:

```
                 |State       | Status   |
-----------------|------------|----------|
clic to start >  |            |          |
                 |Recording   |          |
                 |            | Starting |
                 |            | Recording|
clic to stop >   |            |          |
                 |Stopped     |          |  
                 |            |Finalizing|
                 |            |Loaded    |
```

Error during record:

```
                 |State       | Status   |
-----------------|------------|----------|
clic to start >  |            |          |
                 |Recording   |          |
                 |            | Starting |
clic to stop >   |            |          |
```

---

I have found a solution to prevent crash but it's not pretty. If the audioRecorder is on StratingStatus or FinalizingStatus, I recreate the AudioRecorder.

```
void MyApp::toogleRecord(){

    switch (myAudioRecorder->status()) {
    case QMediaRecorder::LoadedStatus:
        myAudioRecorder->record();
        break;
    case QMediaRecorder::StartingStatus:
        qDebug()<<"ok je suis là en starting";
        createAudioRecorder();
        break;
    case QMediaRecorder::RecordingStatus    :
        myAudioRecorder->stop();
        break;
    case QMediaRecorder::FinalizingStatus:
        qDebug()<<"ok je suis là en finalizing";
        createAudioRecorder();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

If you have other idea why audioRecording stay on status "starting" or "finalizing", don't hesitate.

Comment: Any readable error on crash ?

Comment: No. In reality, it doesn't really crash, the application is blocked at this line and seems not respond (windows grey)

Comment: I would at least check the backtrace - run your app in debug mode and when "crash" happens you will see how was called that line, what are the local variables values etc..

Comment: I suggest create a slot and you connect it to the signal QMediaRecorder::error(QMediaRecorder::Error error) trough that you could get some useful information.

Comment: When I start debug without stop point, I haven't message on "crash".

Comment: what do you mean without stop point? Do you mean that when you start your app in debug mode it doesnt crash? Have you checked the backtrace?

Comment: Same issue here, Qt5.3.1, recording audio/PCM from microphone. Sometimes I am unable to record at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running Linux (Kubuntu 1404). The problem never happens if running the same code in a Linux virtual machine. 
I suspect PulseAudio is the cause.

Comment: @Giancarlo Have you some  idea how to solve the problem ?

Comment: absolutely not, probably it is a Qt bug on Linux platforms. To avoid the problem I just rewrote my code in order to use QAudioInput, but this is not suitable for all the needs :\